# intellij IDEA does not see resources

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I use spring boot.

intellij IDEA does not see resources. How to make intellij IDEA see resources?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2MAH.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome. Please see this post to edit a question for the community to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `href`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bulma.css">
```

That's because your `template` folder is in the same level as `static`

Comment: Das ist nicht die richtige Entscheidung.